# Best practice for sharepoint designer workfow with multiple approval steps and thousands of active workflows

Tags: designer-workflow

As a best practice is it better to have a sharepoint designer workflow pause until a status changes or let the workflow complete and run each time the List Item changes checking the status each time?  There are multiple status "stages" in the workflow.   (IE: submitted, awaiting approval, approved, development, testing, etc..)The list will have probably 2 or 3 thousand active entries.

Thanks!

Comment: I have never came across a best practice for this and I do not think there is one. It depends on the solution you are developing. There are pros and cons for both pausing and completing/restarting a workflow. 
Pausing a workflow prevents users from starting that workflow again, which can happen by mistake: for example, if a user is tries to manually start the workflow after he changes the status. 
Completing and restarting the workflow once the item changed is good when you need flexibility in the approval process: for instance, you want to allow the users to skip a stage for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use pause and go with changes every time item changes.
This allows the workflow to be always in completed state. In case of any updates on workflow you need not worry about the new steps being executed and all.